# javascript set value input field text sharepoint infopath form

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, infopath

I need to include a default value in a "Country" field by java script, this field is added using infopath.

Can anyone help me with a jscript code that places a default value in the field without doing this by infopath itself?

This is more or less like this. *********************************************************************
  $(function () { //change the title name for your single line of text title name $("input[title='Country']").val("United States");   });

Comment: please add some actual code and what you have tried so far.

Comment: please enter your problem with some code snippet so we can understrnd your problem easily..

Comment: This is more or less like this.
***************************************************************************************
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () { 
 //change the title name for your single line of text title name
 $("input[title='Country']").val("United States"); 
});
</script>